# Storing the input in 3 dimentional arrays

Tags: java, arrays, input

I want to store the input for different test cases that want to test with my java program .
below the sample input :

```
1
4 5
2 5 6 8
3 8 5 1 7
```

Here:

- 1st line- No of test cases.
- 2nd line-length of arrays M and N.
- 3rd line- elements of M array.
- 4th line: elements of N array .

My problem , how to store all these elements at run time and given them as input my java class .

Comment: here is the input for better view:
1
4 5
2 5 6 8
3 8 5 1 7

Comment: How are you getting the sample input? Show your code!

Comment: Please show us the code you have written to solve the problem.  Hint: we are not here to do your programming for you ...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To [improve your chances to get constructive answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you should [show us what you have done](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @StephenC , shared the code below,

Answer (score 0):

As @Vamsi krishna suggested, the separate lines for the input are not really relevant. So you can enter the values as arguments to the java command line and read them in your `main` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 0;
    int numberOfTests = Integer.parseInt(args[i++]);
    int mSize = Integer.parseInt(args[i++]);
    int nSize = Integer.parseInt(args[i++]);
    int[] mValues = new int[mSize];
    for(n = 0; n < mSize; n++) {
        mValues[n] = Integer.parseInt(args[i++]);
    }
    int[] nValues = new int[nSize];
    for(n = 0; n < mSize; n++) {
        nValues[n] = Integer.parseInt(args[i++]);
    }
}
```

Then call your application with:

```
java MyApp.class 1 4 5 2 5 6 8 3 8 5 1 7
```

Note: you did not indicate how the number of test cases should be used. If this means multiple groups of m,n arrays can be specified as input an extra iteration is needed and the m,n arrays must be stored somewhere, for example in another array.

If this simple approach is not good enough (it might be too error prone because of the lack of formatting on the input) you could put the input in a file and read it using java.util.Scanner:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    try {
        while (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            // see logic above but use sc.nextInt() to get the next int     value
        }
    }
    finally {
        sc.close();
    }
 }
```

Call this with:

```
java MyApp.class C:\input.txt
```

And put the input in the file C:\input.txt.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
     * Sharing the code here with . Yes,there will be multiple test cases in
     * the input Suggest any better way if you find
     */
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int testcases = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    String readinput = "";
    int count = 0;
    int[][][] array = new int[testcases][3][];
    for (int i = 0; i <= array.length; i++) {
        readinput = "";
        count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            readinput = br.readLine();
            count = readinput.split(" ").length;
            String[] data = new String[count];
            data = readinput.split(" ");
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
            for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {

                array[i][j][k] = Integer.parseInt(data[k]);
            }

        }

    }
```